# How to mock an axios call which returns a image buffer

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a axios api call which returns image buffer like below:

```
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e1 00 de 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 06 00 12 01 03 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 ... 12688 more bytes>
```

My fetch function is implimeted seperately.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const logger = require('./logger');

const imageApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://endpoint',
  timeout: 5000,
});

const fetchRandomImage = async ({ imageId, width, height }) => {

  try {
    // Fetch image
    const response = await imageApi.get(`/id/${imageId}/${width}/${height}`, {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};

module.exports = fetchRandomImage;
```

What is the proper way to implement this test using jest with mock.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to mocking a promise method:

```js
jest.mock("./path-to-fetchRandomImage", () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('whatever-you-want')));
```

Comment: I'm having a different function for axios call. I have updated the question. how can i use that function to write the test?.

Comment: I updated the answer, is this what you mean?

Comment: What i want is the mock function to do this and how to use that mock in test file.  I'm writing the test to above `fetchRandomImage` function

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand :)